# Customizing the TrackBar control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, trackbar

I am trying to develop application that would let me mark A-B points on the timeline. How do I  draw lines on the trackbar to mark a specific point/value?

Also, how do I hide the ticks in the trackbar control when `TickStyle` is set to `Both`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to pay for that DevExpress provides a Trackar which is named RangeTrackBar with 2 TrackBar Buttons and very Customizable using Visual Studio Designer .