# Custom TrackBar with labels for every tick

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I need to make a custom trackbar which needs to look like this one from VMWare: [Image1](http://s21.postimage.org/k0vdl5plj/Capture.png), This is the best I can get: [Image2](http://s3.postimage.org/uej2f969v/Capture2.png)

How am I supposed to do this? I have tried to put labels next to it, but that doesn't seem to work (I can't get them aligned with the ticks (- signs). Does anyone know how to create such a control or how to align the labels? Thanks!

EDIT: And yes, I've searched the web and this site, but I can't find anything that's usefull to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255038/customizing-the-trackbar-control-in-net

Comment: @Syddraf Yea, I found those topics, but they use a custom DLL, which is a no go for me :( and I can't seem to find how they draw the labels there.

Comment: You haven't even mention whether you are using Winform or WPF.

Comment: @Dzienny Ooh, yea sorry I'm using Winforms.